# Why my activity still show the title bar on top?'

Tags: android

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
```

menifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SplashscreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Does your xml has a toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title bar by adding styles for the activity in your manifest file.

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashscreenActivity" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```